# concrete example of ~/.pgpass for PostGreSQL 12 on Debian (Buster) Gnu/Linux?

Tags: linux, postgresql

For the [helpcovid](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid) GPLv3+ project ([git commit `109d5fb90f6ae`](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/commit/109d5fb90f6ae87d170c0739c2c6acd24684815a) ...)  we need a concrete and working example of a running [file `~/.pgpass`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html) on Debian (Buster) Gnu/Linux x86-64.

We are debugging, so we need to be able to do that without root.

[PostGreSQL](https://postgresql.org/) on [Debian](https://debian.org/)/Buster is version 12. I followed instruction in this [README.md](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/blob/master/README.md)

I never deployed any PostGreSQL database in my life.

The below example does not work, I don't understand why (sorry for the comments in French)

```
# fichier ~/.pgpass pour Basile en mars 2020
# voir  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html 
localhost:*:helpcovid_db:helpcovid_usr:test_helpcovid
```

and that file is readable by me only:

```
% ls -l .pgpass 
-rw------- 1 basilest basilegr 164 Mar 22 12:38 .pgpass
```

#### issue solved in [git commit `5733fed27967d13`](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/commit/5733fed27967d13b54f57e87620336a843d7f349)

With our `generate-config.py` python script

---

PS. The https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid project is in March 2020 **work in progress**

Comment: Two things: (1) Your README example uses the password `password`. (2) "On Unix systems, the permissions on a password file must disallow any access to world or group; achieve this by a command such as `chmod 0600 ~/.pgpass`. If the permissions are less strict than this, the file will be ignored." (from the linked Postgre docs)

Comment: Third thing: "Each of the first four fields can be a literal value, or `*`, which matches anything." It doesn't say the port field can be omitted.

Comment: Fourth thing: the README says `export HELPCOVID_POSTGRESQL=postgresql://www-data@localhost/helpcovid_db` which would indicate that the username being used for postgre is `www-data` instead of `helpcovid_usr`. At this point I strongly recommend that you explicitly list out everything you have done related to postgresql in your post instead. And also note everything you have done differently from that README.

Comment: Yes, https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid is work in progress

Comment: **I strongly recommend that you explicitly list out everything you have done related to postgresql in your post instead. And also note everything you have done differently from that README.**

Comment: @muru Please see my attempt in my answer if we can find what went wrong. The project in this question has non-trivial depenceies to pull in.

Comment: @Niklas the problem with the question is that "does not work" is a *useless* statement. What exactly does not work? What was the PostgreSQL configuration used for whatever it is that's not working? Your `psql` command in the answer is working - is it the same thing that's *not* working for Basile? Or is it something else?

Comment: @muru Basile did not respond to this, I will try and get more details. We should solve this

Comment: Does your "issue solved" statement mean that the question is no longer required?

Comment: Yes, question could be removed if so needed

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch please edit your question to remove the "issue solved in ... with ..." part, and add that as a self-answer to this question, ideally an answer which explains how `generate-config.py` works for future people with the same original question as you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it  contains its own solution; the solution part should be edited out and made into an answer.

Comment: Please close the question if possible and needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Ubuntu and could just follow the postgresql guide from this link https://itsfoss.com/install-postgresql-ubuntu/

Then with the project I got a compilation error trying to `make localhost0` but the postgresql connection part with the `.pgpass` did work for me in the following manner.

```
developer@1604:~/proj/github/helpcovid$ sudo su - postgres
postgres@1604:~$ psql -c "alter user postgres with password 'StrongPassword'"
ALTER ROLE
postgres@1604:~$ createuser dbuser1
postgres@1604:~$ createdb testdb -O dbuser1
postgres@1604:~$ psql -l  | grep testdb
 testdb    | dbuser1  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
postgres@1604:~$ psql
psql (11.7 (Ubuntu 11.7-2.pgdg18.04+1), server 9.5.14)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# alter user dbuser1 with password 'StrongPassword';
ALTER ROLE
postgres=# create table test_table ( id int,first_name text, last_name text );
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into test_table (id,first_name,last_name) values (1,'John','Doe');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# select * from test_table;
 id | first_name | last_name 
----+------------+-----------
  1 | John       | Doe
(1 row)

postgres=#
```

Then my connection string is in my home directory

```
$ cat .pgpass 
localhost:5432:testdb:dbuser1:StrongPassword
```

And I can make the connection from the prompt:

```
developer@1604:~$ psql -d testdb -h localhost -U dbuser1
psql (11.7 (Ubuntu 11.7-2.pgdg18.04+1), server 9.5.14)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

testdb=>
```